# Lodash sortBy: order by Boolean with if condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

I want to sort an Array depending on a Boolean, but only if a second condition is true.

I can sort the Array by Boolean like this (I know you could also leave out the if part, but I wanted to see if it works like this.

```
posts = sortBy(posts, [function(post) {
  if (post.featured_post === true) {
    return post
  }
}]);
```

But now I would like to add another condition:

```
posts = sortBy(posts, [function(post) {
  if (post.featured_post === true && post.date >= today) {
    return post
  }
}]);
```

But this does not seem to work anymore. I get pretty random orders.
Maybe I also don't understand how to use the sortBy with a function, so some help is highly appreciated.

PS: I don't get any errors, it just does not sort correctly.

Cheers

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how can post.date > than today? Is this a futuristic time traveling post? Or is this some kind of post dated value?

Comment: can you add a sample of your `posts` ?

Comment: What is the type of `post.date` and `today`? Are they integers? If not, it's probably not going to sort the way you think it should.

Comment: I don't think the function passed to `sortBy` is meant to have branch statements inside. You normally return the value with which you want to be compared in sorting. In your code you say that in some elements what should be compared is `post`, in some others what should be compared is `undefined`.

Comment: @RyanWilson It's post about events, and when they are being written it's about future events.

Comment: @MarinosAn Ok so without branch statements... Any other suggestions to achieve the wanted order?

Comment: @gforce301 The should be javascript Date objects (formatted to display something like this: `today:  1523980800000` – but because of your question I realized that I never transformed the post.date into this format. After a quick test it seemed to make the proper order. I will investigate further... :D

Answer (score 1):

Because of @gforce301 s question I realized that I never transformed the event date into a javascript Date object. By doing this:

```
const today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)

posts = sortBy(posts, [function(post) {
   const postDate = new Date(post.date).setHours(0,0,0,0)
   if (post.featured_post && postDate >= today) {
      return post
   }
}])
```

I actually got the sortBy to work – even with branch statements. Good to have another example of how lodash's sortBy works.

Thanks for your help. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works a bit by random and I think it will be hard to understand / adapt.

What about this one?

```
import { get } from 'lodash/fp'
import { overEvery, sortBy, negate } from 'lodash'

const shouldBeFirst = overEvery(
  get('featured_post'),
  ({ date }) => (new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0)) == (new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))
)

const preSortedPosts = sortBy(posts, 'date')

const sortedPosts = [
  ...preSortedPosts.filter(shouldBeFirst),
  ...preSortedPosts.filter(negate(shouldBeFirst))
]
```

Comment: I've checked out the orderBy but again I could not get the additional condition. What I want to achieve:
I want to have an array where my posts which have `featured_post=true` are upfront. But ONLY if their date is not in the past. So I need this additional condition... and my solution works, so I guess it's ok...